# A seperate network feed from a college network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I don't have much network experience and I have a slightly complicated situation that I am wondering if it is possible to resolve.

Backstory: I live on campus with my family (my wife is professional staff). The wireless here drops often partially because of the signal being 15-30 ft away through walls of concrete and also because of what looks to be a 2002 wireless AP. I looked for all solutions to not use the college internet with options ranging from a hotspot to a Line of sight internet of which had awful signal and no line of sight. The college owns all hardlines into the area which was also out of the question. After a short and quick discussion we were allowed to run our own AP just for us. This is great news but I am grabbing at more.

The college actively blocks about every port and piece of traffic between devices on the network. I want to know, Is it possible to set up a network behind an AP or router so that my devices can talk with each other but on the AP/Router side out to the college is one MAC address.

This is a mock up of what I want. 
[image: current want]

Comment: It's hard to see what your question is. Just set things up exactly like you showed in the picture. This is precisely what the vast majority of routers do in their default configuration.

Comment: I might not understand your question, but that is what a router does. If you can get to a hardwired ethernet connection, then plug a router in. Everything you hook to on the LAN side of the router will be yours and reachable beween each other. Everything on the WAN side looks to be coming from the same system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set-up a Wi-fi network at Home?](https://superuser.com/questions/440910/how-to-set-up-a-wi-fi-network-at-home)

Comment: And if you can't get a hardwired connection, there are specialized PTP (direct link) Wi-Fi devices. (Though, speaking as IT tech at _another_ college which provides internet access to employees... the sooner we get rid of them, the better.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want your home gateway router/AP to do is called NAT (technically NAPT), and it is the default behavior of all home gateway routers.

They have a single public IP address and MAC address on their Ethernet WAN port, and that single IP address and MAC address is all the outside world sees.

On the private LAN side (both wired and wireless LAN), they give out private IP addresses and let all your home devices talk to each other, but when any of your home devices make outgoing connections to the Internet, the NAT gateway functionality of the router makes all the traffic look like it's coming from the router's public IP address and MAC addresses.